# When do browsers send the Origin header? When do browsers set the origin to null?

Tags: http, firefox, cors, cross-domain, fetch-api

As you can see from [this Bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446344) (and [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034776/why-does-firefox-not-always-send-the-http-origin-header-for-post-requests)), Firefox does not always send an Origin header in POST requests. [The RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7) states that it should not be sent in certain undefined "privacy-sensitive" contexts. Mozilla defines those contexts [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Origin#Privacy-Sensitive_Contexts).

I'd like to know whether these are the only situations in which Firefox will not send the Origin header. As far as I can tell, it also will not send it in cross-origin POST requests (though Chrome and Internet Explorer will), but I can't confirm that in the documentation. Is it enumerated somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: That means, in order to prevent attacks (especially CSRF), one has to handle this in the backend (even though they use CORS restrictions, or Same-origin policy), and disable requests with null origin header.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

As far as what the relevant specs actually require, the answer has a couple parts:

- **When browsers must internally set an origin to a value that gets serialized as `null`**
- **When browsers must send the Origin header**

Here are the details:

#### When browsers must set origin to a value that gets serialized as `null`

The HTML spec uses the term [opaque origin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-origin-opaque) and defines it as an “internal value”:

> with no serialization it can be recreated from (**it is serialized as "null"** per ASCII serialization of an origin), for which the only meaningful operation is testing for equality

In other words, everywhere the HTML spec says *opaque origin*, you can translate it to `null`.

The HTML spec requires browsers to set an opaque origin or unique origin in these cases:

1. [Cross-origin images (including cross-origin `img` elements)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#origin:img-req-data)
2. [Cross-origin media data (including cross-origin `video` and `audio` elements)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#origin:media-data)
3. [Any document generated from a `data:` URL](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#origin:document-4)
4. [Any `iframe` with a `sandbox` attribute that doesn’t contain the value `allow-same-origin`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-iframe-sandbox)
5. [Any document programmatically created using `createDocument()`, etc.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#origin:document-16)
6. [Any document that does not have a creator browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#windows:concept-origin-2)
7. [Responses that are network errors](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#process-a-navigate-response)
8. [The *Should navigation response to navigation request of type from source in target be blocked by Content Security Policy?* algorithm returns Blocked when executed on a navigate response](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#process-a-navigate-response)

The Fetch spec requires browsers to set the origin to a “globally unique identifier” (essentially the same thing as “opaque origin”, which basically means `null`…) in one case:

8. [Redirects across origins](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-request-tainted-origin%E2%91%A0)

The URL spec requires browsers to set an opaque origin in the following cases:

9. [`blob:` URLs](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-origin)
10. [`file:` URLs](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-origin)
11. [any other URLs whose scheme is not one of `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `ws`, `wss`, or `gopher`](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-origin)

But note that just because the browser has internally set an opaque origin—essentially `null`—that doesn’t necessarily mean the browser will send an `Origin` header. So see the next part of this answer for details about when browsers must send the `Origin` header.

---

#### When browsers must send the Origin header

Browsers send the `Origin` header for WebSocket requests and for cross-origin requests initiated by a `fetch()` or XHR call, or by an ajax method from a JavaScript library (axios, jQuery, etc.) — but not for normal page navigations (that is, when you open a web page directly in a browser), and not (normally) for resources embedded in a web page (for example, not for CSS stylesheets, scripts, or images).

But that’s a simplification. There are cases other than WebSocket requests and cross-origin XHR/fetch/ajax calls when browsers send the `Origin` header, and cases when browsers send the `Origin` header for embedded resources. So what follows below is the longer answer.

---

In terms of spec requirements: The spec requires the `Origin` header to always be sent for WebSocket requests and for any request which the Fetch spec defines as a [**CORS request**](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-request):

> A **CORS request** is an HTTP request that includes an `Origin` header. It cannot be reliably identified as participating in the CORS protocol as the `Origin` header **is also included for all requests whose method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`**.

So, what the spec means there is: The `Origin` header is sent in all cross-origin requests, *but* it’s also always sent for all `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` requests — even for **same-origin** `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` requests (which by definition in Fetch are actually “CORS requests” — even though they’re same-origin).＊

---

The other cases when browsers must send the `Origin` header are any cases where a request is made with the “CORS flag” set — which, as far as HTTP(S) requests, is [*except* when the **request mode** is `navigate`, `websocket`, `same-origin`, or `no-cors`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch).

XHR *always* sets the mode to `cors`. But with the Fetch API, those request modes are the ones you can set with the `mode` field of the init-object argument to the `fetch(…)` method:

```
fetch("http://example.com", { mode: 'no-cors' }) // no Origin will be sent
```

Font requests always have the mode set to `cors` and so always have the `Origin` header.

And for any element with [a `crossorigin` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-settings-attribute) (*aka* “CORS setting attribute”), the HTML spec requires browsers to set the request mode to `cors` (and to send the `Origin` header).

Otherwise, for embedded resources — any elements having attributes with URLs that initiate requests (`<script src>`, stylesheets, images, media elements) — the mode for the requests defaults to `no-cors`; and since those requests are `GET` requests, that means, per-spec, browsers send no `Origin` header for them.

When HTML form elements initiate `POST` requests, the mode for those `POST`s also defaults to `no-cors` — in the same way embedded resources have their mode defaulted to `no-cors`. However, unlike the `no-cors` mode `GET` requests for embedded resources, browsers do send the `Origin` header for those `no-cors` mode `POST`s initiated from HTML form elements.

The reason for that is, as mentioned earlier in this answer, browsers always send the `Origin` header in all `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` requests.

Also, for completeness and to be clear: For navigations, browsers send no `Origin` header. That is, if a user navigates directly to a resource — by pasting a URL into an address bar, or by following a link from another web document — then browsers send no `Origin` header.

---

＊ <sub>The [algorithm in the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#append-a-request-origin-header) that requires browsers to send the `Origin` header for all CORS requests is this:</sub>

<sub>To append a request `Origin` header, given a request *request*, run these steps:</sub>

<sub>1. Let *serializedOrigin* be the result of byte-serializing a request origin with *request*.</sub>

<sub>2. If *request*’s response tainting is "`cors`" or *request*’s mode is "`websocket`", then

    append `Origin`/*serializedOrigin* to *request*’s header list.</sub>

<sub>3. Otherwise, if *request*’s method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`,

    then: *[also send the `Origin` header in that case too]*</sub>

<sub>Step 2 there is what requires the `Origin` header to be sent in all cross-origin requests — because all cross-origin requests have their response tainting set to "`cors`".</sub>

<sub>But step 3 there requires the `Origin` header to also be sent for **same-origin** `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` requests (which by definition in Fetch are actually “CORS requests” — even though they’re same-origin).</sub>

<sub>The above describes how the Fetch spec currently defines the requirements, due to a [change that was made to the spec on 2016-12-09](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/commit/eb89fcd54bb39e81b11c569f6ad7ba615883f7b9). Up until then the requirements were different:</sub>

<sub>•  previously no `Origin` was sent for a same-origin POST</sub>
  <sub>•  previously no `Origin` was sent for cross-origin POST from a `<form>` (without CORS)</sub>

<sub>So the Firefox behavior the question describes is what the spec *previously* required, not what it *currently* requires.</sub>

Comment: can you genearlize it a little:  Header is always included except when it's not Get/Head request think [Post], and if it's made by JS XHR then mode is CORS and then headers are included as well, however, with fetch you can change mode and headers wont be included. 

So does that mean img tag which makes get request without using JS (fetch/xhr) won't have headers origin and referrer sent

Comment: do you know if there any way that I can set the origin header to `null` in ajax CORS request without having to create a sandboxed iframe and communicate with it using postMessages - wish to do anonymous requests

Comment: Explaining _"8. The Should navigation response to navigation request of type from source in target be blocked by Content Security Policy? algorithm returns Blocked when executed on a navigate response"_. ||| These are **Content-Security-Policy (CSP) blocked navigation responses.** The term ["navigation responses"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#navigation_directives) refers to the locations a user can navigate to (via `<a>`, `<iframe>`, `window.location`) or submit a form to (via `<form>`). `fetch` responses are not considered in this rule.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, your answer somehow became **the** source for an complete overview of when the `Origin` header has value `null`. Even [_MDN docs_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin#description) refer to your answer. I've been looking through the various (outdated) links that you provided, and I wasn't able to find any source for your statements, beside the ones in the question. How did you find, e.g. the case with the Content-Security-Policy?

Comment: After some further digging, it seems that the previous specifications provided some more details, or have since been removed. Moreover, it seems your answer conflicts regarding `websocket`. You mention that Origin header is sent for request modes except `navigate`, `websocket`,... . However, from the Fetch spec that you link in the footnote, it says: [_"If request’s ... mode is "websocket", then append (`Origin`, serializedOrigin) to request’s header list."_](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#append-a-request-origin-header)

Comment: Great Summary! But also reveals the inglorious messy state of web security standards.

Answer (score 5):

For me this was happening on a super-standard form POST to a relative URL on localhost, and seems to have been triggered by having

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

in the `<head>`.

Changing it to

```
<meta name="referrer" content="same-origin">
```

seemed to make Firefox happier.

Comment: Simple and quick, thanks

Comment: Thank you, that helped me track it down. In my case, it was the `Referrer-Policy no-referrer` header that cause the Origin to not be set (and subsequently the request to be denied because of CORS).

Comment: But this is for the `referer` header only. Not the `origin` header with OP is talking about.

Comment: @KernelJames That’s the point—you’d think that this only affects the `referer`, but when set to `no-referrer` it also causes the browser to send `Origin: null`.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>I wanted to add some information to [@sideshowbarker's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242802/3673659), which has become the most comprehensive source on this topic and is even linked to by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin#see_also). To supplement this answer, I reviewed various specifications and identified some changes that have occurred since the answer was first posted. I also organized the information to make it easier to read. In addition, I used [WebArchive](https://web.archive.org/) references from early 2023 instead of direct links, since the specs may change in the future.</sub>

<sub>It's important to note that both [@sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) and my answer should be used as guidelines, as implementations, rulesets, and flavors are up to the discretion of browser maintainers.</sub>

<sub>Use them as guidelines and if you're uncertain, be sure to perform tests.</sub>

---

As [@sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) mentioned, the various specifications define a null [`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) header as:

- opaque origin
- null origin

With this, we can filter through the specifications to figure out when the `Origin` header is `null`:

- **`GET` or `HEAD` requests that do not allow [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) or use [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).** For all other [request modes](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326054246/https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) that use `same-origin`, `navigate` or `no-cors`, the Origin header is omitted. Some Web APIs allow you to specify the `mode`, such as [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), while others have default values, such as an `<img>` requesting an external resource: <sup>1, 2</sup>

  - **Any embedded HTML element that requests its content via a URL.** These elements include `<link>`, `<script>`, `<img>`, `<audio>`, `<video>`, `<object>`, `<embed>`, and `<iframe>`. These HTTP `GET` requests use the `no-cors` mode by default, unless a `crossorigin` attribute is set on the HTML element. Note that `<canvas>`, `<math>`, and `<svg>` are not included, as they cannot request data from external resources (e.g. with a `src` attribute). <sup>1, 2, 3</sup>
  - **Any `GET` or `HEAD` `fetch()` request where the `mode` option has the value `"navigate"`, `"same-origin"`, or `"no-cors"`.** By default, `fetch()` uses the `cors` mode. <sup>1, 2</sup>
  - (Sidenote: *[`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), unlike `fetch` does not allow setting a `mode` and defaults to `cors`, meaning all `XMLHttpRequest`'s are sent with the Origin header.*)<sup>4</sup>
- **[`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) set to `no-referrer` for any requests that does not use a `GET` or `HEAD` method and doesn't use `cors` or `websocket`.**<sup>5</sup>
- **Responses that are network errors**. A 404 or 500 HTTP response status is no network error, since the the request was successfully able to reach the server. Rather invalid protocol, header or where the server fails to send a response. <sup>6</sup>
- **[Content-Security-Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) blocked navigation responses.** The term ["navigation responses"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#navigation_directives) refers to the locations a user can navigate to (via `<a>`, `<iframe>`, `window.location`) or submit a form to (via `<form>`). `fetch` responses are not considered as navigation responses. <sup>7</sup>
- **URL schemas**:

  - **Any embedded inline file created with the [`data:` scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)**<sup>8</sup>
  - **The `file:` scheme may omit the Origin header** (Browser dependent) <sup>9</sup>
  - **In some cases for the `blob:` scheme** <sup>10</sup>
  - **Any other URL whose scheme is not one of `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `ws`, `wss` or `gopher`** <sup>11</sup>
- **Some browsing contexts have no Origin**. A [browsing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context) is an environment in which a web page or application is displayed, which can be a *tab*, a *window* or even only parts of a page, like a *frame* or an *iframe*. A [creator](https://wicg.github.io/controls-list/html-output/multipage/browsers.html#creator-browsing-context) (referred to as *"creator browsing context"* in previous HTML spec's), is the browsing context which was responsible for creating another browsing context. There exist two types of creators, the *[opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) browsing context* (e.g. clicking a link to another page, the page embedding the link is the opener) and the *[parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) browsing context* (e.g. the page embedding an iframe is a parent browsing context). The HTML specification considers the following cases without Origin header:

  - **Any `<iframe>` with a `sandbox` attribute that doesn't contain the value `allow-same-origin`**<sup>12</sup>
  - **Any document created programmatically** using `createDocument()` or that do not have a creator browsing context. <sup>13, 14</sup>

---

###### References:

<sup><sup>1</sup> [The fetch spec says that Origin is included for all requests except `GET` or `HEAD`.](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326054246/https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-requests)</sup> 
<sup><sup>2</sup> [The fetch spec says that `mode` with `cors` or `websocket` are send with the Origin header, excluding all other modes.](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326054246/https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#append-a-request-origin-header)</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> [Default mode of the `Request()` constructor used for `fetch` and embedded HTML elements](https://web.archive.org/web/20230429103416/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/request/mode#default_mode)</sup> 
<sup><sup>4</sup> [The XHR spec says that default mode of `XMLHttpRequest` is set to `cors`](https://web.archive.org/web/20230429103416/https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-send)</sup> 
<sup><sup>5</sup> [The fetch spec mentions this in Bullet point #3.1.](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326054246/https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#append-a-request-origin-header)</sup>
<sup><sup>6</sup> [The HTML spec says that a network error should return no navigation params, which include origins. See Bullet point #21 (Not # 19.21)](https://web.archive.org/web/20230427030454/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#create-navigation-params-from-a-srcdoc-resource)</sup> 
<sup><sup>7</sup> [The HTML spec says that a "Blocked" CSP response leads to a network failure. See Bullet point #6.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20230427030454/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#process-a-navigate-response) which [the CSP specs defines as a network error](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#should-block-navigation-response) resolving in reference 5.</sup>
<sup><sup>8</sup> [The HTML spec says that `data:` scheme returns an opaque origin](https://web.archive.org/web/20230427030454/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#script-settings-for-workers)</sup> 
<sup><sup>9</sup> [The URL spec says that the reader should decide how to handle the `file:` scheme but suggest to use an *opaque origin*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326050906/https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-origin)</sup> 
<sup><sup>10</sup> [The FileAPI spec lists some specific cases when an *opaque origin* is used](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326050906/https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#originOfBlobURL)</sup> 
<sup><sup>11</sup> [The URL spec lists these URL schemes and fallbacks to *"opaque origin"*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326012622/https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#origin)</sup> 
<sup><sup>12</sup> [The HTML spec specifies to return an *"opaque origin"* for this iframe case context. See Bullet point #5](https://web.archive.org/web/20230427030454/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#creating-browsing-contexts)</sup> 
<sup><sup>13</sup> [The HTML spec says that a `Document` without browsing context has an *"opaque origin"*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230427030454/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#resource-metadata-management). Moreover, the HTML spec says that [`Document`'s' created with `createDocument()` have no browsing context](https://web.archive.org/web/20230427030454/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#windows)</sup>