# Should I send any Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to non-allowed origins in the actual request following the OPTIONS request?

Tags: cors, cross-domain, preflight

I have a general idea about how it works. I return the same "ORIGIN" value if the the request's "origin" header is valid (allowed)

But I don't know:

1. For the actual request following the OPTIONS request, do I need to include the exact same Access-Control-Allow-Origin header that I returned to the client for the preflight request?  Should the server code only need to do this when there is an "ORIGIN" header present in the actual request? (in the code below, I did not check whether the request is a OPTIONS/preflight request or the actual one, I assume the same code can apply to both with no harm).

(More details,  because "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'," so I need the ORIGIN value from the request to put back into the response.

2. What should I return if the ORIGIN is not allowed?

   not including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header at all?
   or setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ""),
   or setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "null")?

```java
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

    String origin = requestContext.getHeaderString("Origin"); 


String origin = requestContext.getHeaderString("Origin");

    URL originUrl = null;
    try {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(origin)) {
            originUrl = new URL(origin);
            
            Pattern hostAllowedPattern = Pattern.compile("(.+\\.)*mydomain\\.com", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            if (hostAllowedPattern.matcher(originUrl.getHost()).matches()) {
                headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            } else {
                headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "");
            }
            headers.add("Vary", "Origin");
        }

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> For the actual request following the OPTIONS request, do I need to include the exact same Access-Control-Allow-Origin header that I returned to the client for the preflight request?

Yes—that is, if you’re sending back an actual origin value and not the "`*`" wildcard, and that origin value is what caused the `OPTIONS` request to succeed. Because if you send back a different non-wildcard origin value than what the `OPTIONS` succeeded with, that’ll cause the browser to block the client code from accessing the response (because the actual origin won’t match).

> Should the server code only need to do this when there is an "ORIGIN" header present in the actual request?

Yes, because when frontend JavaScript code running in a browser uses XHR or the Fetch API or an Ajax method from some JavaScript library to make a cross-origin request, browsers always add an `Origin` header to the request. And `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is only used by browsers.

So there’s no point in sending back `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to non-browser tools that haven’t sent an `Origin` in the request—in that case, it’s just wasted bytes you’re sending out.

Of course somebody can use `curl` or whatever non-browser tool to send a request to the server, and manually add an `Origin` header to the request. But that’s OK—in that case, the response they’ll get is the same response you’d send to a browser. So that can actually be helpful for testing.

> What should I return if the ORIGIN is not allowed?
>   not including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header at all?

Yes. Just don’t send back the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header at all for those cases. That’s the semantics of the header being missing: If the server sends no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, that means the server isn’t opting in to allowing cross-origin requests from frontend code running browsers, so the default same-origin policy applies.

That is, by not sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, the server’s telling browsers: *“Please use the default same-origin policy as usual and prohibit access to this response from all frontend JavaScript code at the origin that sent this request.”*

> or setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ""),

No, there’s never any need to send back an empty value like that. It doesn’t mean anything special.

> or setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "null")?

Definitely don’t do that. There are many cases where a browser will send an `Origin` header with the value `null` and unless you intentionally want to allow all requests with `Origin: null` to access responses from the server, don’t do that.

For details, see the ***When browsers must internally set origin to a value that’ll get serialized as `null`*** part of the answer at *[When does Firefox set the Origin header to null in POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239643/when-does-firefox-set-the-origin-header-to-null-in-post-requests/42242802#42242802)*

Comment: so there is no need to check if it is a preflight call? no need to worry about previous calls?

Comment: I’m not 100% clear on what you’re asking, but if what you’re asking is—in terms of your code—that for the preflight you check the `Origin` header against `hostAllowedPattern`, then yes, you should. As far as that goes, your code shouldn’t treat preflight OPTIONS requests any differently than normal GET or POST requests—all should be checked against `hostAllowedPattern` in the same way. Of course in other ways your code otherwise needs to respond differently to the preflight OPTIONS than to other requests, but that’s a different matter (e.g., the OPTIONS response  should have no response body).