# Request origin null does not have permission to access the resource

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

I'm trying to get CORS working but I'm getting error "Request origin null does not have permission to access the resource." only when the application is deployed to the server. I have checked the headers and the request does include an "origin" header with the domain of the page that initiated the request, but still I get the above error, as if the header is not being sent as part of the request.

This is the CORS policy I'm using:

```
      builder.WithOrigins("https://*.mydomain.com")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
```

Everything works locally when using the same configuration. Could it be that a load balancer is removing the header for security? Also I'm using ".AllowCredentials()" on the call to setup CORS in the startup class.

Comment: Browser always send the Origin header for cross-origin requests — but there are a number of cases in which the browser will end up setting the Origin value to null. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239643/when-do-browsers-send-the-origin-header-when-do-browsers-set-the-origin-to-null/42242802#42242802. Maybe the case that people run into most often is, If the request has ended up getting redirected across origins.