# Cors Erorr in Spring Boot due to SAML?

Tags: spring-boot, cors, saml, adfs

I have the following setup:
A Spring-Boot web server with ADFS Single Sign-on over SAML which I based on this project https://github.com/isaacgarza/saml-example instead of Maven I’m using Gradle if that matters.

The Login and normal functionality are working just fine.
except a CORS Error with one of two Error messages in the Browser:

- case one

[image]
[image]

- case two

[image]
[image]
[image]

- if askt the url direktly
  [image]

and always the same Error in Spring

```
2021-09-02 09:48:25.042 DEBUG 80412 --- [io-10009-exec-5] o.a.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport     : Error trying to obtain a certificate from the client
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:556) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.getPeerCertificateChain(JSSESupport.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
```

I have tried a dozen variants of CORS implementations with **@CrossOrigin** and **Global CORS configutation** but none of my implementations leads to the desired behavior.

I send a *Get-Request* to my *Spring-Server* and instead of processing this *Get-Request* the *Spring-Server* redirects this to the *ADFS* and now the error message occurs because *ADFS* can’t handle this – naturally.

**Question**: How can I prevent this redirecting of the *Get-Request* (of the *Spring-Server*) to the *ADFS*?

I appreciate any hints or code chunks **and** when any additional information is needed let me know – I will edit my post.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Redirecting should not cause any CORS issue. why there are two different ports 10000 and 10009?

Comment: 10000 is the Frondend and 10009 is the backend

Comment: can you paste response headers for normal req-res without adfs or saml in picture.

Comment: if i use the url directly there is a normal response (hope it is the picture you wanted)

Comment: Just wondering - if you have ADFS 2019, did you enable CORS? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/customize-http-security-headers-ad-fs

Comment: Okay, that is weird. because in case1, it clearly mentions that it is blocking from localhost:10009 while the origin is localhost:10000 - two separate ports will be considered as different origins

Comment: A cross-origin redirect will cause the browser to set the value of the Origin request header to null. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242802/441757. So if the responding server is doing a check of the Origin value against a list of allowed origins, that check will fail.

Comment: @rbrayb yes we are using ADFS 2019 
and haven’t enabled CORS till now I will try with the ADFS Admin on Monday.

Comment: @DerTyp, may i  please know if you got a chance to enable CORS ? and if the issue is till there?

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT the problem is still there but I am only allowed to look for a solution on the side.