# CORS - Redirect Origin is Null

Tags: cors, fetch

I have a CORS issue that I can't seem to figure out. In the client I call my server `xyz.com` from a `subdomain.xyz.com` on the server I respond with Allow Origin `subdomain.xyz.com` however the server determines that the request should go through a third subdomain like `sumdomain-2.xzy.com` now the JS Fetch does a follow to the redirect and that Request will have a null Origin, therefore getting rejected by the server since the origin is no longer `subdomain.xyz.com` .

What am I doing wrong? and is there a workaround this?

```
#Redirector is used for testing.
Request URL:
https://example.com/redirector?url=https://2.example.com/test



#Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.25.2
Date: Thu, 07 Sep 2023 11:56:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: User-Agent
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://1.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Location: https://2.example.com/test
Set-Cookie: SES=2bb6e51d371052a7ee0c60a4e5f447f3; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=None

#Request headers
GET /redirector?url=https://2.example.com/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Origin: https://1.example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://1.example.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"



# Redirect Call would be to /test
https://2.example.com/test
#Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.25.2
Date: Thu, 07 Sep 2023 11:56:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: User-Agent
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://1.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization
Location: https://www.example.com/login?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2F2.example.com%2Ftest
Set-Cookie: SES=3f660180a56712e99b933d108ca9ade9; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=None


#Request headers
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 2.example.com
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://1.example.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
```

I tried to set the Origin on the redirect response on the server but Like I assumed that does not work since the Origin is determined by the browser.

Comment: Please provide the according headers. What do you mean by "the server determines ... should go through?" You must ignore all the reverse proxy domains and provide the host that the client is requesting in the allow origin header.

Comment: The server would check for the user Datacenter and redirect to the correct DC subdomain.

Comment: Before redirecting we set the origin as the allowed origin, which would be the original `sudomain.xyz.com` but the redirect will have a null origin.

Comment: @DanielW. I added the headers for the request I am using for testing. You can see in the first request the server is responding with the specific Access headers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access-Control-Allow-Origin equals origin but the browser still denies access... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494027/access-control-allow-origin-equals-origin-but-the-browser-still-denies-access)

Comment: @jub0bs Thank you, That was precisely what I did to resolve the issue on my end. I was looking for a server-side solution to avoid many front-end rewrites. But it was the last resort to call the direct subdomain and remove the redirect.