# Laravel redirection failed with CORS error

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cors

I have a Laravel API, and I am trying to redirect the user back to my website (Angular), but it is not working. This is the Laravel snippet.

```
public function payViaApplePay(Request $request)
{
    $paymentId = $request['payment_id'];
    $paymentData = $request['payment_data'];

    $results = $this->service->payViaApplePay($paymentId, $paymentData);

    $redirect_url = $this->service->getRedirectURL((array)$results);
    return redirect()->away($redirect_url);
}
```

and this is the error in the browser

> [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200

I tried to add origin header in the redirect, but It didn't make any difference. How can I solve it? or is there a better way to do the redirection?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494027/access-control-allow-origin-equals-origin-but-the-browser-still-denies-access/69497937#69497937

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought of the solution they provided at the end where I should handle it from the frontend side but I am not fully convinced to apply it yet, I will research a little bit more how to solve it (if possible), but thank you again for the mentioned question it really helped me to understand the problem better.

Answer (score -1):

It might help you. I had this error before.
I create a new middleware named EnableCors

```
php artisan make:middleware EnableCors
```

and put this data in the handle function

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');

    return $response;
}
```

and in Http/Kernel.php file update this parts:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EnableCors::class, // add this
         \\ ...

    ],
];


protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnableCors::class, // add this
    // ...
];
```

(all my APIs started with /api prefix so I only added this middleware for the routes that started with /api prefix if you don't you can add these lines in other middleware groups )

after these changes my problem with the same error code fixed

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: Why is this necessary? What does this do that Laravel's built-in CORS middleware isn't doing?

Comment: @miken32 A pertinent question...

Comment: CORS stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. It is a mechanism that allows you to make requests to a different domain than your own securely. It defines a set of headers the server can use to control which origins can access its resources. ...
See this for more information: https://laravel-news.com/diving-into-cross-origin-resource-sharing

Comment: @MohammadSalehnia What's your point? By linking to that section of MDN Web Docs in my earlier comment, I meant to say that `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` doesn't allow credentialed access when you also use the wildcard (`*`) in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, as you do in your code.