# How to send non-empty Origin header in POST request if running an app on localhost?

Tags: python, django

I just upgraded to Django 4 and it includes [the ticket 16010](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16010) with [csrf origin verification changes](https://github.com/django/django/commit/2411b8b5eb65fe3d7bcc1ee1f59e2433520c7df6#diff-eaa105f5b436e20dd838c27c7a753ef4cf888edcc8f868c084600f6cb7343166R227).

To my knowledge, if you are running an app on localhost, browsers won't send origin (they will [send null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239643/when-do-browsers-send-the-origin-header-when-do-browsers-set-the-origin-to-null/42242802#42242802)). So, whenever we run a Django app on localhost, we should expect a header `Origin: null` in POST requests.

But with the recent change CSRF on localhost can't be validated because of another change - `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` now need to have a scheme. [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0)

Is it possible to add a non-empty `Origin` header when POSTing from localhost?

To be clear, this won't work

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + ('Access-Control-Allow-*',)
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    ]
```

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

> ```
> Origin checking failed - null does not match any trusted origins.
> ```

Request headers

```
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Origin` will be `null` in many different cases. My problem was that I had

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

in the base template.

Comment: `more_set_headers 'X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block';` can also make problems on OpenResty...