# `<script>` tag loading error details with cross origin requests

Tags: javascript, html, cors

In my react app, I am attaching a `script` tag to load a script resource dynamically from CDN. The host page domain is of course different than CDN domain.

My question is, in `production`, if my CDN response **does not** contain `access-control-allow-origin` header, and my `<script>` tag in DOM **does not** contain `croossorigin`, will errors generated by the CDN script resource be hidden by the browser and resulting only in `Script error.` message ?

And if so, will adding `croossorigin` to `<script>` tag and ensuring CDN responds with `access-control-allow-origin: *` header allow seeing the actual error that happen in the script (assuming I have `onerror` handler on the script element)

Comment: Scripts are allowed by default cross-origin, you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: As I understand it, scripts are allowed to load and execute cross origin, but when errors happen in the script loaded from a different domain, these errors' details aren't exposed to the script on host domain. If my understanding is wrong, what is the `crossorigin` attribute on script tag for ?

Comment: Question: *“will adding `croossorigin` to `<script>` tag and ensuring CDN responds with `access-control-allow-origin: *` header allow seeing the actual error that happen in the script (assuming I have `onerror` handler on the script element)”*. Answer: Yes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#notes and for a spec reference, see the part of the algorithm algorithm at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetch-a-classic-script where *muted errors* gets set.

Comment: Here's where I'm very confused - in one of my tests scenarios, I am seeing the opposite where having no `croossorigin` attribute on `script` tag  and not having `access-control-allow-origin: *` in response headers would still show me the error generated by a script from another CDN domain. The request also does not contain `origin` header - could that be it ? If no `origin` header is present, errors are visible ?

Comment: I should also mention in case that matters that my `script` tag is added the DOM via another script

Comment: If the request has no Origin header, then either it’s a same-origin request — not a cross-origin request — or it’s not initiated by some element that has a `crossorigin` attribute, or not from frontend JavaScript code, but instead from some other runtime, or from somebody just doing a normal navigation. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239643/when-do-browsers-send-the-origin-header-when-do-browsers-set-the-origin-to-null/42242802#42242802