# Programmatically submitting a form on an iframe sets origin to null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, http

I'm looking to programmatically submit a form that will return HTML to be rendered by an iframe. In the past, we have been able to pass along information to the backend via query string parameters. However, the query strings have started to get too long. So, we decided to start passing information via the body of a `POST` request.

The problem is that now that I am sending it as a POST request, the `origin` is being set to `null`. The parent window and the url of what is returned by the POST request have different sub-domains (`global.mycompany.com` vs `customer.mycompany.com`) which may be contributing to that `origin` being set, but I can't tell for sure. I've never had to worry about the `origin` being set before, it has always just worked. Unfortunately in this case, if the `origin` is `null`, the backend is having a difficult time authenticating correctly and accurately processing the long info that is passed in the body of the POST request.

Is there a way I can set the `origin` myself (or ensure that it does not get set to `null`)? I haven't been able to find any information suggesting that I can, but I'm hoping someone is an html spec guru that could help out.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {useEffect, useRef, useCallback} from 'react';
import {USER_NAME, USER_FULLNAME} from 'CurrentUser';
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const formRef = useRef(null);
  const uniqueKey = useRef(uuid());

  const submitLaunchForm = useCallback(() => {
    if (formRef.current !== null) {
      formRef.current.submit();
    }
  }, [formRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check some various conditions, but ultimately just decide when to submit the form
      submitLaunchForm();
  }, [submitLaunchForm /*, various condition dependencies */]);

  return (
    <>
      <form
        ref={formRef}
        target={`appFrame-${uniqueKey.current}`}
        action={`/my-url`}
        method="post"
      >
        <input type="hidden" name="userName" value={USER_FULLNAME} />
        <input type="hidden" name="userEmail" value={USER_NAME} />
        <input type="hidden" name="longInfo" value={LONG_INFO} />
      </form>
      <iframe
        name={`appFrame-${uniqueKey.current}`}
        title="Custom App"
        allowFullScreen
        sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-downloads"
        referrerPolicy="origin"
        src=""
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

What I've researched so far includes this S/O answer:
[When do browsers send the Origin header? When do browsers set the origin to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239643/when-do-browsers-send-the-origin-header-when-do-browsers-set-the-origin-to-null/42242802#42242802)

Which links to this spec:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-iframe-sandbox

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example? This seems to have nothing to do with reactJS you just submit a form to iframe. Which can be coded in Pure HTML. Check if submitting the form with a button will give you the same results if not then you can just put a simple `script` with one line to submit the form. I would also check if removing the sandbox will make any difference, I never used this param but `allow-same-origin` may be related to the issue that you have different domains.

Comment: I can't really create a minimum working example because it will require hosting pages that will be returned by a backend (from different subdomains) so it's not like I could throw this up on codepen (for example). The reason I tagged `reactJS` is because I submitted an example of the code that I'm working with and it is using react on the frontend.

Comment: I know why you tagged ReactJS but even if you put ReactJS code this question has nothing to do with React. This is just form + iframe. And by creating a minimal example I can't run your code and see what happens, isn't it? Create a minimal working example that you can run. It doesn't have to be a codepen it can be git repo. If you ask questions or report a bug to any Open Source project you mostly like will be asked exactly the same Please create a reproduction so we can test the issue. Please confirm that the minimal example still has the problem.

Comment: What happens is when a person creates a reproduction it turns out that it works and the problem is in a different place, also often the person who created the reproduction finds the issue on their own while creating a reproduction. This is needed so you don't waste people's time.