# Webpack 4 Hot Reload: Invalid Host/Origin header

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working with webpack-dev-server to do hot reloading. However in my console it keeps saying `Invalid Host/Origin header`

The setup I have in my webpack config is as follows:

```
'use strict'

const webpack = require('webpack')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',

  devServer: {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    hot: true,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ...
  ]
}
```

How do I solve this issue so that it works in my dev environment? Would love the hear this as currently I have to refresh the page constantly.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the end it was an update on the package that didn't come through properly and was solved after installing the newest build.

Answer (score 34):

This issue is probably caused by this webpack-dev-server [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1604) that has been fixed recently.

To avoid getting the `Invalid Host/Origin header` error add this to your `devServer` entry:

```
disableHostCheck: true
```

Comment: This is insecure solution. And the issue still exist in the latest build.

Comment: @Jangid It only affects the dev-server I might hope. So how would that be insecure?

Comment: `ng serve --disableHostCheck=true` was the only thing I found that fixed this error for me on IE11

Answer (score 7):

Set `allowedHosts`, https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts. For example, if your web page is `xyz.google.com`, then just add a host `.google.com` to it.

Answer (score 4):

Is your page hosted at a different domain than your webpack files are being served from? If so, you might just need to add the page's domain to the [`devServer.allowedHosts`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-allowedhosts) option.

Answer (score 2):

If this is on Firefox, you can fix it by setting `network.http.sendOriginHeader` to `1` in `about:config`.

This **"Invalid Host/Origin header"** error occurs on Firefox because Firefox still [does not sent Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50030134/328565) with same-origin POST requests, and `webpack-dev-server` insists on having it.

(Really, `webpack-dev-server` should only check the `Origin` header when it's present.)

Avoid `disableHostCheck`! It's dangerous even in your local dev environment! It allows attackers to connect to your dev environment when you visit an unrelated site with malicious code. It seems [really bad](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a).

Answer (score -1):

Update your `webpack-dev-server` to >= version 3.1.14 (as of Jan-2019)

```
npm i -D webpack-dev-server@3.1.14
```

The respective issue occuring in `~3.1.11` has been patched.

No change to the webpack configuration is required.

Comment: Whatever was patched didn't fix much. I have this problem with `webpack-dev-server@3.1.14`, but only with Firefox.